# how can I var dump a block/node content in drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to override block theme and rebuild it with html and twig.

I cant seem to find the variables from the block type or content type and cant find the image url for example.

how can i reach it using kint?

Comment: You should try drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to dump everything is with

```
{{ dump() }}
```

inside your twig template.

I work on fairly large Drupal sites, and I use this to not exhaust the memory from looping through vars.

```
<ol>
    {% for key, value in _context  %}
      <li>{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

This will dump everything into a nice ordered list.

Hope this helps!

Also I'm not sure if you're already doing this, but if not -- turn on the twig debug tool, then check out your inspector of choice, and it'll give you suggestions and override data.

You can do this inside your sites/default/services.yml with

```
twig.config:
debug: true
```

Comment: The loop is awesome! Thanks. +1

Comment: @Guru are you adding the markup to your template files? this part doesn't go in services.yml it goes into the template file where you want to know what variables are available in the presentation layer. For example if you put this inside of page.html.twig you should see a lot.

Comment: I've mentioned "twig.config: debug: true " lines added into services.yml file

Comment: Did you try using the <ol> snippet in your template file? turning on debug: true also adds template suggestions into your inspector if you need to make sure you're putting it in the right template file.

Answer (score 3):

If you have kint (of Devel module) installed, just use:

`{{ kint(_context) }}`

Its better than `{{ dump() }}`, cause kint can manage when the recursion is too long, avoiding memory issues. Second, have a nice way to display the information.

Comment: I agree. Kint is much better. It also allows you to click on the array element that you want and copy the `path` to it. It also gives you a list of available methods which makes it easier to get access to protected values.